# Flutter "Mailer" API Multiple Image Attachments

Tags: android, email, flutter, dart

I'm making a simple app for getting personal information from the user and number of images to send them through backend mail API with a one click of a button. So far, I can get and send the FormData through mail but I couldn't figure it out the how to send an array of images.

I have tried several API's but "Mailer" seems to best for SMTP. As for the code, I tried to convert the "File" class to String or List but none of those have worked for me. I'am not a intermediate coder so be kind with me :)

That's how I get the images using "image_picker"

```dart
File _image1;

Future getImage1Camera() async {
    var image1 = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
     _image1 = image1; 
    });

  }
```

And the "mailer" code

```dart
void _mailer() async{

  if(!_formKey.currentState.validate()){
    return;
  }else{
    _formKey.currentState.save();
  }

  String gmailUsername = '**';
  String gmailPassword = '**';

  final smtpServer = gmail(gmailUsername, gmailPassword);

  final ceSendMail = Message()
  ..from = Address(gmailUsername, '')
  ..recipients.add('recipent')
  ..subject = 'Test'
  ..text = 'Plain Text'
  ..html = ''//Form Data
  ..attachments.add(_image1);//TODO: User input images

  try {
    final sendReport = await send(cekSendMail, smtpServer);
    print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
  } on MailerException catch (e) {
    print('Message not sent.');
    for (var p in e.problems) {
      print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
    }
  }
  // Create a smtp client that will persist the connection
  var connection = PersistentConnection(smtpServer);

  // Send the message
  await connection.send(cekSendMail);

  // close the connection
  await connection.close();

}
```

This is the error I get and whatever I try it's always the "type" error.

`The argument type 'File' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Attachment'.`

So, how can I get multiple image files from user and send through mail API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your file with `FileAttachment`

```
..attachments.add(FileAttachment(_image1))
```